# How to make StreamBuilder for location is on or off in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have to make **StreamBuilder** for **location service** which checks if location is **on or off**.

here, i have to **display data screen** if location is on and if location is off then **display location off screen**.

Here when i off the location service of device then automatically shown the Location Off screen and when i on the location service then automatically shown the Data screen.

So how i can do this, Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator package which has some good examples. From their docs:

"To listen for service status changes you can call the getServiceStatusStream. This will return a Stream which can be listened to, to receive location service status updates."

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

StreamSubscription<ServiceStatus> serviceStatusStream = 
  Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream().listen((ServiceStatus status) {
        print(status);
  });
```

In order to listen for location updates you can use:

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

final LocationSettings locationSettings = LocationSettings(
  accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
  distanceFilter: 100,
);

StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream =
  Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings)
     .listen((Position? position) {
         print(
             position == null
                ? 'Unknown'
                : '${position.latitude.toString()}, ${position.longitude.toString()}'
         );
     });
```